# Express JS Controllers with Socket IO Issue

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am trying to setup Socket IO to work well in different controllers in my Express application.

Here is how I have Socket IO initialized in my server.js

```
//Run When Connection Received
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.emit('message', 'This is a test message from the server.')
})
```

Here is what one of my controllers looks like:

```
const getComments = asyncHandler(async (request, response) => {
    const { liveID, token: accessToken } = request.body
    var source = new EventSource(
        `https://streaming-graph.facebook.com/${liveID}/live_comments?access_token=${accessToken}&comment_rate=one_per_two_seconds&fields=from{name,id},message`
    )
    source.onmessage = function (event) {
        // Do something with event.message for example
        console.log(event)

        // THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO EMIT A SOCKET IO EVENT.
        // THE DATA IN 'event' NEEDS TO BE SENT BACK TO THE CLIENT VIA THE SOCKET

    }
    source.onerror = function (error) {
        console.log('Error!')
        console.log(error)
    }

    source.onopen = function (event) {
        console.log(event)
    }
})
```

I have been trying to follow this documentation from Socket IO but for the life in me I can not seem to figure out how to make this work with my above example I have tried so many different things and I just seem to be missing something.

https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-application-structure/

Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you add the client code where you are connecting to your socket.io server? It will be easier to provide a useful answer if that was added. Otherwise answers will look more like tutorials again.

Comment: The client code is kind of irreverent to this question.  The controller is getting a stream of comments from the Facebook API.  When it receives on it should emit a message to the client.  The client side is having no issues catching socket IO messages.  The issue I am having is configuring my controller to be able to emit socket IO messages since controllers are separate files from the server.js file.  Unfortunately all of the "tutorials" and examples show initializing and sending/receiving messages all from one single server.js file.

Comment: ok, thanks, it makes sense now.

Comment: Are you trying to broadcast or send to a specific user? Or a specific group of users? If group of users, do you need authentication to verify they can receive the messages? You say "sent BACK to the client" but like... did the client request this action in the first place?

Comment: There will only ever be one client connected to this app.  This is just one part of it but currently I am just trying to get the stream of live video comments coming from the facebook API to be sent back to the connected client.  I know how to do that part.  The part I am unable to figure out is how to be able to call on Socket IO inside of my controller files rather then inside of my server.js file where I am initializing the Socket IO server.

Comment: So inside of server.js I am initializing socket.io, but then from inside my Express controller files I need to be able to do socket.emit.  The problem is socket is initialized inside server.js not inside that controller file.  So I need to be able to call socket.emit and link it back to the main server.js file.   I think this is trying to show how to make that work https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-application-structure/#each-file-registers-its-own-event-handlers but I cant figure out how to tie that all together with my example above.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do to have access to ***io*** in controller is to attach it to request object like so:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    req.io = io;
    next();
});
```

When a socket connects add an user id to the socket

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    // assuming you send user id in a header for example
    socket.userId = socket.client.request.headers.userId;
})
```

Then in a controller:

```
const getComments = asyncHandler(async (request, response) => {
    var io = request.io;

    // https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-api/#serverfetchsockets
    // return all Socket instances
    const sockets = await io.fetchSockets();

    // assuming there's a loggedin user object attached to request
    const socket = sockets.find(s => s.userId === request.user.id);

    const { liveID, token: accessToken } = request.body
    var source = new EventSource(
        `https://streaming-graph.facebook.com/${liveID}/live_comments?access_token=${accessToken}&comment_rate=one_per_two_seconds&fields=from{name,id},message`
    )
    source.onmessage = function (event) {
        // Do something with event.message for example
        console.log(event)

        socket.emit(....);

    }
    source.onerror = function (error) {
        console.log('Error!')
        console.log(error)
    }

    source.onopen = function (event) {
        console.log(event)
    }

})
```